# Laravel pivot table joined with pivot table

Tags: laravel

I have following Database Tables

```
User
-idUser

Products
-idProducts

Product_Collector
-Product_CollectorID
-idProducts (foreign)
-idUser (foreign)

Ticket
-idTicket
-Product_CollectorID
```

Currently I'm modeling all these Database Tables in Laravel. 
But I'm struggeling with the function to get the Products associated with the Tickets. 
Do I have to create a model for the Product_Collector? Or is there any other good solution?

Comment: Perhaps this is what you seek? https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: unfortunately not, because it's only for already exitsting models